# Is there a way to change a vlookup table_array in VBA?

Tags: vba, vlookup

Basically, I am trying to use VBA to change the VLookup table_array from one tab to another.  Currently the VLookup value is something like this

=+vLookup($A4,'02.19.21'!$A$1:$O$9000,F$1,False)

02.19.21 is the name of a tab the data is pulling from, but every week a new tab is created with the most recent data, so the next week the data will need to pull from a new tab that will get created called "02.26.21"

I need vba to change '02.19.21' to '02.26.21', which is where the new data will be pulled from

Edit, I have tried doing a macro recorder, but the issue is that the data is changing weekly,  meaining, if I record and change the date to 02.26.21, then when i need to do it for the next week, march 5th, it would not return that data.
I tried the date function in VBA and then used it as a string, since the vlookup would be looking at a tab that is called 02.26.21, but got errors when I did that.

Comment: Hi, Please could you update your question with what have you tried? Did you try using the macro-recorder to capture manually performing that change and then review the generated code as a starting point? And does it need to be VBA?

Comment: If you use a named range in your formulas instead of the table range address, you only need to update the named range and you're done...

Comment: @TimWilliams, I am unsure what you mean by that.  I'm not the greatest with VBA, so can you explain what you mean by a named range?
I need the VBA script to understand that the tab it is pulling from is the tab of that day.  So  if I ran the script on Feb 24, I need the script to know that the tab it will pull from is Feb 24th tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a named range for your vlookups instead of a direct sheet+range reference.

See here for named ranges for example: https://www.contextures.com/xlnames01.html

So your vlookup goes from this:

```
=+vLookup($A4,'02.19.21'!$A$1:$O$9000,F$1,False)
```

to this:

```
=+vLookup($A4,LookupTable,F$1,False)
```

So then when your code needs to change the source sheet, you can do something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("LookupTable").RefersTo = _
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("02.26.21").Range("A1:O9000")
```